# Integral test error approximation

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Find an N so that:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$ is between $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^4}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^4} + 0.005$

I am getting N = 200.

Is this correct? I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Are you supposed to know the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$ ?

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} > \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n^4}$ for any finite positive integer $N$. So the only relevant part would be  $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} < \sum_{n = 1}^N \frac{1}{n^4} + 0.05$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $\sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} < .005$.

We have the integral comparison 
$$\int_{N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4}< \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}< \int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4}$$
or

$$\frac{1}{3(N+1)^3} < \sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} < \frac{1}{3N^3}$$

The equation $\frac{1}{3N^3} = 0.005$ has the solution $N = 4.05...$ and we see that

$$\frac{1}{3 \cdot 5^3} < \sum_{n = 5}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} < \frac{1}{3\cdot 4^3}$$

or

$$ 0.00266 < \sum_{n = 5}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} < 0.00520$$

Still that does not guarantee that the remainder starting with the fifth term is less than $0.005$ but we are close. Let's get a better approximation:

$$\sum_{n = 5}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{1}{5^4} + \sum_{n = 6}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4}< \frac{1}{5^4}  + \frac{1}{3\cdot 5^3} = 0.0016+ 0.00266... = 0.00426... < 0.005$$

Thus the first such $N$ is $4$ ( anything larger OK too).

$\bf{Added:}$

Thanks to the observation of @Claude Leibovici:  we check

$$\frac{\pi^4}{90} - ( 1+ \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} + \frac{1}{4^4}) =0.00357...$$ while

$$\frac{\pi^4}{90} - ( 1+ \frac{1}{2^4} + \frac{1}{3^4} ) = 0.00747...$$

Comment: Sorry.. shouldn't the integral of 1/x^4 be -1/(3x^3)? Your's is not negative

Comment: Yes, the indefinite integral, and it's used to calculate a definite integral with the upper limit $\infty$

Comment: On your last line of work, towards the end you have 1/(5^4) + (1/(3(5^3)))
Where are you getting the 5 from in here "(1/(3(5^3)))"? Your series is from n=6 to inf, so I would assume you should have it as "(1/(3(6^3)))"

Comment: @user141750: there is a lower bound and an upper bound, stated  before